# Painted image with rounded rect in QTableView seems to be fixed on

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm using a `QDelegate` to display an image in `QTableView` with rounded corners. The basic implementation is working, but as soon as I resize the whole `QMainWindow` where the table is located the image stays fixed at it's original position and the grid lines are moved over the image.

How to mount the image to the cell instead of the table?

I've tried `QLabel` and `QPixmap` / `QPaint` with no result. The working example is enclosed.

```
import pathlib
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800,600)

        self.table = QTableView()

        data = [
          ['Line 1', 'c:/daten/dummy/image1.png', 19],
          ['Line 2', 'c:/daten/dummy/image2.png', 29],
          ['Line 3', 'c:/daten/dummy/image3.png', 39],
          ['Line 4', 'c:/daten/dummy/image4.png', 49]
        ]

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setRowHeight(0, 200)
        self.table.setRowHeight(1, 200)
        self.table.setRowHeight(2, 200)
        self.table.setRowHeight(3, 200)

        imageDelegate = ImageDelegate (self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, imageDelegate)
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader ()
        header.setSectionResizeMode (1, QHeaderView.Stretch)

class ImageDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__ (self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        image = str(pathlib.Path(index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)))
        imagetoshow = QImage(image)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(imagetoshow)
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(400, 400, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        #pixmap.set
        option.widget.setRowHeight(index.row(), pixmap.height())
        option.widget.setColumnWidth(index.row(), 400)
        ##
        brush = QBrush(pixmap)
        painter.setRenderHint (QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setBrush (brush)
        painter.drawRoundedRect (option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), pixmap.width(), pixmap.height(), 20, 20)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using the pixmap as a brush, and in that case it's treated as a texture, which normally has an *origin* at (0, 0).

To avoid that you can use [`setBrushOrigin()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setBrushOrigin) with the top left point of the `option.rect`.

Note that you should always prefer to [`save()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#save) and [`restore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#restore) the state of the painter when changing its properties (font, pen, brush, brush origin, background, render hints, clipping and transformations), and the state **must** be always restored (every `save()` has to be matched by a corresponding `restore()`). This is very important for functions that *receive* an already constructed QPainter, like in this case with the `paint()` function.

```
        brush = QBrush(pixmap)
        painter.save()
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setBrushOrigin(option.rect.topLeft())
        painter.drawRoundedRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), 
            pixmap.width(), pixmap.height(), 20, 20)
        painter.restore()
```

On the other hand, you can also use clipping and directly draw the pixmap:

```
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), 
            pixmap.width(), pixmap.height(), 20, 20)
        painter.save()
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.topLeft(), pixmap)
        painter.restore()
```

Finally, you should **never** change view properties within the paint event, most importantly because it could cause recursion (and in the best case it will at least cause unnecessary redraws, like in your case), but also because it's not the good way to do so.
Also, it doesn't make much sense that you use `setColumnWidth` with the index *row*.

Since you're already using the 400 pixel limit, you can set the second column width `Fixed` and resize the column for the header, then use `ResizeToContents` for the vertical header and implement the [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) for the delegate. Alternatively, you can use the `ResizeToContents` mode for the column too.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Fixed)
        header.resizeSection(1, 400)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

class ImageDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    # ...
    def sizeHint(self, opt, index):
        image = str(pathlib.Path(index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)))
        imagetoshow = QImage(image)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(imagetoshow)
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(400, 400, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return pixmap.size()
```

Comment: Ok, now I see how it should work. I use your clipping idea, it looks straight to me. I did not understand by reading the docs, but this explanation let me see my general misunderstanding. One more thing: Where to locate loading of the image, because it must checked if it exists and other things before painting? Actually it works only if I place a function named `check_image(self,index):` which return a valid path in both `createEditor` and `sizeHint`?